# Удалить элемент из RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, циклы, recyclerview

Имеется RecyclerView с 2-мя ViewHolder'ами, куда приходит JSON-объект, в котором есть список, который я собственно и отображаю. Но по моей задумке, я должен получать два типа элементов, вместо трёх.
Первый - TYPE_TEXTVIEW; 
Второй - TYPE_EDITVIEW;
и третий - все остальные. Третий элемент у меня в списке(изображенном ниже) отображается как "Not found".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посоветовали удалить(отсортировать) из самого моего списка данный элемент, путём создания цикла:

```
public void onResponse(Call<DropDown> call, Response<DropDown> response) {
            DropDown jsonResponse = response.body();
            for(Groupss g :jsonResponse.getForm().getmGroupss()) {
                if (g.getmControls() != null && g.getmControls().size() > 0 && "type".equals(g.getmControls().get(0).getTitle())) {
                    mList.add(g);
                }
            }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как удалить ненужный элемент в методе?

Comment: мне кажется, что один из элементов соответствует вашему условию для NOT_FOUND - `if (mList.get(position).getmControls().size()>0)` для него не выполняется, или же `mList.get(position).getmControls().get(0).getTitle()` не совпадает со строками из `case`

Comment: @metalurgus Допустим вы правы, как можно решить проблему?

Comment: Добавьте, например, какой-то лог в `getItemViewType()`, и посмотрите, правильно ли я предположил.

Comment: @metalurgus Там где default:
                temp =1;
Дополнительно прописать default:
               Log.d("check", String.valueOf(temp =1)); ? Немного теряюсь...

Comment: перед `return temp;` напишите `Log.d("check","return " + temp + "; position = " + position);`

Comment: @metalurgus в логах значения такого типа:
D/check: return 1; position = 5

Comment: Абсолютно все с типом 1?

Comment: @metalurgus нет, есть 1/-1 ну и position тоже разные

Comment: -1 и есть ваши NOT_FOUND.

Comment: @metalurgus и как сделать так, чтобы они не отображались в моём списке?

Comment: предварительно удалить их из `mList`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45351/discussion-between-vadim-morozov-and-metalurgus).